# Adding to a specific group

Tags: civicontribute

I am creating a wordpress based website with Civicrm. Now users can register by submitting a membership form and they will become member of a group called Free Members. FreeMembers can access a contribution form to make membership fee, after making the membership fee how can I include those members to a group named PaidMembers ? 
I am using CiviCRM 4.4 on Wordpress latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possibilities I think. I can think of two:

1. Use the membership status rules. If the membership is created
   initially I reckon they would get the status 'pending', which is
   then changed to 'new' (or 'current' depending on your setup) once
   they pay. You can use this in Smart Groups to distinguish between
   the two. More background in the [user guide on memberships](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/membership/defining-memberships/) This
   is for 4.6, but the concepts have not changed dramatically from 4.4
2. Use the CiviRules extension to get what you want. There is a
   [wiki](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/membership/defining-memberships/) explaining what CiviRules can do.

I would prefer the first option as I think you can manage this with core CiviCRM but it would require you to study and configure your membership statusses?